# ejbAccessException when starting JNLP java application

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb, jnlp

I am trying to run a jnlp file that is downloading some jar files to jvm cache and I started to get the following error on start time:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/ejb/EJBAccessException
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.executeApplication(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.executeMainClass(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.doLaunchApp(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.ejb.EJBAccessException
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.jnlp.JNLPClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 9 more
```

What my cause this javax.ejb.EJBAccessException? Here is my jnlp file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="http://10.100.10.9/ikarusdelhitest/" href="ikarus.jnlp">
<information>
    <title>ikarus</title>
    <vendor>my company name here</vendor>
    <homepage href="http://www.mycompanynamehere.com" />
    <description>description here</description>
    <icon href="ikarus.ico" />
    <offline-allowed />
</information>
<security>
    <all-permissions />
</security> 
<resources> 
    <jar href="jars/ikarus/ikarusClient.jar" />
    <jar href="jars/ikarus/ikarusDelegators.jar" />
    <jar href="jars/ikarus/clientRules.jar" />
    <jar href="jars/ikarus/ruleImps.jar" />
    <jar href="jars/ikarus/ikarusUtil.jar" />
    <jar href="jars/ikarus/ikarusResources.jar" />
    <jar href="jars/ikarus/domain.jar" />
    <jar href="jars/ikarus/domain_repository.jar" />
    <jar href="jars/ikarus/domain_service.jar" />
    <jar href="jars/ikarus/app_repository.jar" />
    <jar href="jars/ikarus/app_service.jar" />
    <jar href="jars/ikarus/infrastructure.jar" />
    <jar href="jars/ikarus/integration_domain.jar" />
    <jar href="jars/jboss_ejb_auth/ejb3-persistence.jar" />
    <jar href="jars/jboss_ejb_auth/jboss-ejb3x.jar" />
    <jar href="jars/jboss_ejb_auth/jbossall-client.jar" />
    <jar href="jars/jasper/commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar" />
    <jar href="jars/jasper/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar" />
    <jar href="jars/jasper/commons-digester-1.7.jar" />
    <jar href="jars/jasper/commons-logging-1.1.jar" />
    <jar href="jars/jasper/iText-2.1.0.jar" />
    <jar href="jars/jasper/jasperreports-3.6.0.jar" />
    <jar href="jars/jasper/poi-3.2-FINAL-20081019.jar" />
    <property name="jnlp.localization" value="Delhi"/>
</resources>
<application-desc main-class="com.celebi.ikarus.main.Ikarus" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution deep inside the jar ocean of my application. Basically, the jar resource files are ALL needed to be signed via a keystore and they should ALL include a META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file which must include those lines in it:

```
Codebase: *
Permissions: all-permissions
Application-Name: <your application name here>
Caller-Allowable-Codebase: *
Trusted-Library: true
Application-Library-Allowable-Codebase: *
```

(don't forget to add an emtpy line at the end of manifest file otherwise it can't be parsed properly.)

Also you need to have the .jnlp  file included in all jars wrapped with a JNLP-INF folder.(i.e. there must be a JNLP-INF folder that includes .JNLP file inside it for ALL of your jar archives in your application. Even in 3rd party jars. Also take care to name your jnlp file with capital letters like MYAPPLICATION.JNLP not myapplication.jnlp)

All in all, you should always hold your java console open whilst you are troubleshooting something about your java application. You shouldn't even see any warnings at java console because generally java console warnings are far more serious for java virtual machine that it actually does not run your application due to the warnings that are not resolved.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a JRE in your resources, to benefit from the standard library.

Try to add `<j2se version="1.6+"/>` before the first `<jar>` tag.

Comment: Indeed, according to http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/EJBAccessException.html is part of the Java EE API, not part of the Java SE API. I'm not sure if it's possible to connect to an EJB from an application deployed with Java Web Start (and I believe it's a funny idea) but in this case you probably need to add some Java EE implementation in your classpath, such as JBoss or Glassfish.

Comment: Well actually this application runs on Jboss_4.2.1 enterprise server and I have the EJBAccessException.class file in one of the many jars of the project. Maybe I am missing something to add to class path? Can I solve this classpath problem somehow from jnlp file?